# The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported Soap Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, wsdl

I've built and API in nodejs with the library "soap" that consumes a wsdl project.

I'm trying to do a post and in the response body I'm getting this error:

> **The server cannot service the request because the media type is  unsupported**

also in the response body I have this message:

> **Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8**.

I did some research and figure it out that is a problem of soap version between server and client.

I try this things:

1. when creating soap client added `forceSoap12Headers:false` and viceverse
2. rewrite soap library with accept content and content-type to: `text/xml; charset=utf-8`, also change all schemes that belongs to soap v1.1
3. try do add `httpHeader` in request `'Accept' 'text/xml'`

This is part of my code:

```js
 MethodTest: async function(wsdl){
            try{
            var client  =  soap.createClient(wsdl,{forceSoap12Headers:false},async (err,result)=>{
                if(err){

                }else{
                    var descripcion = await this.ServiceDescription(wsdl); 
            if(!descripcion.error){
                var body = { _xml:  "<i0:GetAccountBalance>"+
                   "<i0:dc>"+
                      "<i0:RequestId>000</i0:RequestId>"+
                      "<i0:SystemId>WEB</i0:SystemId>"+
                      "<i0:SourceId>AR</i0:SourceId>"+
                      "<i0:AccountNumber>42526372</i0:AccountNumber>"+
                   "</i0:dc>"+
                   "<i0:dcSecurity>"+
                      "<i0:WebUser>NDsVwQwRbwbuY / DcX2PRGw ==</i0:WebUser>"+
                      "<i0:WebPassword>/d8zOcR9K9xqpl8CdhUJrw==</i0:WebPassword>"+
                   "</i0:dcSecurity>"+
                "</i0:GetAccountBalance>"}
                try{
                var response = await (result[descripcion.metodos[8]+"Async"])(body)
                }catch (e){
                    console.log(e.response)
                }
            }

                }
            })
```

Comment: I'm actually suprise that someone is still using SOAP.

Comment: any idea what is happening here? Im stuck

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to setup soap, but it seams like your server cannot access text/xml. And that's what your front-end is sending. Maybe add text/xml as accepted content type to your server headers ?

Comment: or try to add `content-type: application/soap+xml` as your request content type.

Comment: I tried to override headers in http libray  that cames as dependecy of soap library, but still getting same error...

Comment: @Nicolas sadly for us, some under-the-radar companies and developers still use it

Comment: @zyrup I guess it should not suprise me. I mean, some mainframes are still running on COBOL, SOAP is the internet data transfer protocol equivalent of COBOL.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found it. I Had two problems, when creating the client service the default endpoint was set wrong and required the Content-Type **application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8**. I just Override the endpoint and the request went OK!!

Answer (score 10):

For me,

1. I went to headers, deselected the original Content-type
2. Then went to presets, clicked manage presets
3. There, I clicked Add, then in the popup 
   a. Choose a Header Preset Name (anything will work) 
   b. For key -- enter Content-type 
   c. For value -- enter text/xml 
   d. Last click Add at bottom right corner
4. Close the manage preset popup
5. Click your new preset, then select the new Content-type at the bottom

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I wonder why adding Content-Type directly as a key didn't work but using this preset does...

Comment: Apart from god only this solution can be worked.

Answer (score 3):

Here'e what I got to fix the error in my case. Go to Headers first: then if you can be able to change, right at the spot, the default content-type value from application/xml to text/xml try edit that first. If not uncheck content-type checkbox and in the same column at the bottom just type content-type for the Key and text/xml for the value. Then it works perfect !!!

Answer (score 0):

First you should start with SOAPUI which is a free program that can do the SOAP call for you.

Second, you need to check the Content-Type, in my case the server only accepted text/xml;charset=UTF-8

So you can do this in Postman but it's not at all easy to figure out the Content-Type.  You will need to set the request body to XML and override the Content-Type default (which is application/xml or something)